# React Native pod install error: NoMethodError - undefined method `framework?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I keep getting this error in "pod install" while the pod file is the same since last successful install! I've been having this problem for few days now.

NoMethodError - undefined method `framework?' for nil:NilClass
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/target.rb:112:in`build_as_framework?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:53:in`select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in`each_key'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `block in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in`each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:37:in`validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:590:in `validate_targets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:158:in`install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in`run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in`'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in`'

```
――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
```

Comment: Did you got the answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete Pods/* , Podfile.lock and retry

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29847777)

Comment: this worked for me too.